# Finding Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions for a Sturm-Liouville Problem

Tags: fourier-analysis, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

I have the following problem:

> Find all Eigenvalues and associated Eigenfunctions for
>
> $Y'' + LY = 0$,
>
> $Y(0) + Y'(0) = 0$,
>
> $Y(\pi) + Y'(\pi) = 0$,
>
> $x \in (0,\pi)$.

So far, I have tested $L$ less than zero and found a contradiction because I believe it forces a $(L = a^2)$ to be zero. $L = 0$ yields only the trivial solution. 
When I test $L>0$ I find that a must be an integer, but I am lost as to how I find the associated Eigenfunction for this value.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of
$$
        Y''+LY=0 \\
        Y(0)+Y'(0)=0
$$
are simplified by adding normalization such as $Y(0)=1$. The solutions are
$$
        Y_L(x)=\cos(\sqrt{L}x)-\frac{\sin(\sqrt{L}x)}{\sqrt{L}}.
$$
These solutions satisfy $Y(0)+Y'(0)=0$, including the limiting case where $L=0$, which is $Y_0(x)=1-x$. $L$ is a valid eigenvalue iff $Y_L$ satisfies the required endpoint condition at $x=\pi$, which holds iff $L$ satisfies
$$
            Y(\pi)+Y'(\pi)=0,
$$
or equivalently,
$$
        \cos(\sqrt{L}\pi)-\frac{\sin(\sqrt{L}\pi)}{\sqrt{L}}-\sqrt{L}\sin(\sqrt{L}\pi)-\cos(\sqrt{L}\pi)=0 \\
          \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{L}}+\sqrt{L}\right)\sin(\sqrt{L}\pi)=0.
$$
There are solutions $\sqrt{L}=n\pi$ or $L=n^2\pi^2$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$, as well as $L=-1$. The solution for $L=-1$ is
$$
           Y_{-1}(x)=\cosh(x)-\sinh(x) = e^{-x}.
$$